# `python3.7: bad interpreter: No such file or directory`

Tags: virtualenv

I installed Python, pip3, and virtualenv as in [this guide for TensorFlow](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip):

```
brew install python
pip3 install -U virtualenv
```

Then I was able to create a virtual environment with:

```
virtualenv --system-site-packages -p python3 ./venv
```

Then I tried installing TensorFlow with

```
pip install --upgrade tensorflow
```

but it failed [because TensorFlow is not yet compatible with Python 3.7](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/17022). So I removed Python 3.7 with `brew remove python` and installed 3.6.7 from [an installer](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-367/). But running the same `virtualenv` command now fails:

```
$ virtualenv --system-site-packages -p python3 ./venv
-bash: /usr/local/bin/virtualenv: /usr/local/opt/python/bin/python3.7: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
$ which python3
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3
```

So the `virtualenv` link to the executable lists the newest Python version, even after removal.

Furthermore, `virtualenv` lists `brew` as the user group, which is also confusing:

```
$ ls -la /usr/local/bin/virtualenv
-rwxr-xr-x  1 user  brew  232 29 Nov 17:06 /usr/local/bin/virtualenv
```

I've tried uninstalling `virtualenv` with both `pip` and `pip3` and I get:

```
Skipping virtualenv as it is not installed.
```

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 13):

After a few hours, one solution was to install `virtualenv` again with `pip`, then remove it with `pip`:

```
$ ls -la /usr/local/bin/virtualenv
-rwxr-xr-x  1 user  brew  232 29 Nov 17:06 /usr/local/bin/virtualenv
$ pip install virtualenv
...
$ pip uninstall virtualenv
...
$ which virtualenv
$ ls -la /usr/local/bin/virtualenv
ls: /usr/local/bin/virtualenv: No such file or directory
```

And then install it again with `pip3`:

```
$ pip3 install virtualenv
Collecting virtualenv
...
Installing collected packages: virtualenv
Successfully installed virtualenv-16.1.0
```

Notice the use of `pip3`, and not `pip`, unlike [this link](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/installation/), pointed to by [TensorFlow](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip).

And now creating the virtual environment works:

```
$ virtualenv --system-site-packages -p python3 ./venv
Running virtualenv with interpreter /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3
Using base prefix '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6'
New python executable in ~/venv/bin/python3
Also creating executable in ~/venv/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...
done.
```

Answer (score 12):

I created a symlink instead of copy.

```
brew install python@3.7
ln -s /usr/local/opt/python@3.7/bin/python3.7 /usr/local/opt/python/bin/python3.7
```

Comment: Creating the symlink worked for me. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

In my case, I had installed pipenv **on MacOS** with:

```
brew install pipenv
```

It was trying to use Python 3.6 instead of the 3.7 I actually had.

So I solved the issue by uninstalling:

```
brew uninstall pipenv
```

...then installing again with `pip`:

```
pip3 install pipenv
```

Comment: doesn't work for me. I'm using asdf and an existing pipenv installation.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I was on **MacOS** and I had python3.9 installed, but virtualenv was installed using python3.7 and at some point I uninstalled python3.7.

```
$ /usr/local/bin/virtualenv --version
-bash: /usr/local/bin/virtualenv: /usr/local/opt/python/bin/python3.7: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

However, my python version:

```
$ which python3.9
/usr/local/bin/python3.9
```

No amount of pip or pip3 install/uninstall/install virtualenv worked for me.
Finally I did the following:

```
$ python3.9 -m pip install --user virtualenv
Collecting virtualenv
  Using cached virtualenv-20.4.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl (7.2 MB)
<snip>
Successfully installed appdirs-1.4.4 distlib-0.3.1 filelock-3.0.12 virtualenv-20.4.6
```

And then

```
$ /usr/local/bin/virtualenv --version
virtualenv 20.4.6 from <mypath>
```

Yay!!

Answer (score 1):

Try installing python@3.7 via homebrew and then `cp`ing that installation into the directory the program expects to find it.

```
brew install python@3.7
cp -r /usr/local/opt/python@3.7/bin/python3.7 /usr/local/opt/python/bin/python3.7
```

Comment: Why copy instead of symlink?

Answer (score 1):

That solved the problem in my case: (my env file is called `.venv)`

```
mv .venv .venv_old
python3.7 -m venv .venv
source .venv/bin/activate
pip install wheel
pip install --upgrade pip wheel setuptools
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case what solved the situation was adding a line at the end of the `~/.zshrc` file:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin:$PATH
```

hope it helps.

[source](https://blog.adafruit.com/2020/05/29/installing-the-latest-version-of-python-on-mac-os-catalina-python-mac-apple-catalina-letsbsocial1/)